# How to add target of NLog to a specific textbox control, so the log messages will be shown in that control

Tags: configuration, winforms, nlog

I have used following config of NLog to add the log text to control of specified Name on specified form.

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <targets> 
    <target name="control" xsi:type="FormControl" append="true" 
            controlName="textBox1" formName="Form1"/> 
  </targets> 
  <rules> 
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="control"/> 
  </rules> 
</nlog>
```

I have a form with name Form1 and  control on it with the name textBox1.
Still nLog cretes a new form in runtime and adds a docked textbox to it and shows the logs in it.

Now how to make nLogwrite the logs to MY form and MY Control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the issue:

The names used in config are case sensitive.

`textBox1` should have been `TextBox1`